# How to set a value in a bootstrap modal and then pass it in a disabled textbox?

Tags: javascript

I would like to set a value via a form in a modal and have that value reflected on a disabled textbox in the main screen. What are the best options out there?

Answer (score 0):

It can make work using jQuery with the help of event handler

Handle click event of modal dialog, pass data by selecting #Id into modal and show it

Something like.,

```
$(document).on("click", ".open-modalDialog", function () {
     var mytxtInput1Id = $(this).data('txtInput1');
     $(".modal-body #txtInput1").val( mytxtInput1Id );
     //you have call modal to open here
     $('#addModalDialog').modal('show');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is bootstrap5:

It seems like you should only get the value after the modal closes... which is what the function attached to `myModalEl.addEventListener` does.

`event.target` typical returns the element that has the event listener attached to it, but like I said in the comments in the code below, if it doesn't, then there are a million and one different ways to do so.

```
var myModalEl = document.getElementById('myModal');
myModalEl.addEventListener('hide.bs.modal', function (event) {
  // getElementsByName returns a list of elements, so be sure to select an element to perform on
  document.getElementsByName("name_of_hidden_element")[0].value = event.target.getElementsByName("name_of_element_inside_of_modal")[0].value
  //event.target.... should work to get the element from inside the modal, but if it doesn't there are several other ways to do so.
});
```